# Pig: Slow Group By operator

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

After benchmarking Hive and Pig, I found that the Group By operator in Pig is drastically slower that Hive's. I was wondering whether anybody has experienced the same? And whether people may have any tips for improving the performance of this operation? (Adding a DISTINCT as suggested by an earlier post on here doesn't help. I am currently re-running the benchmark with LZO compression enabled).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are looking in the wrong way. Group By just groups the data in some way, it is very important what you do afterwards. When trying to analyze performance in Pig, you should keep these things in mind:

1) Several statements can be merged into a single MR job, so don't look at the statements, look at the performance of the generated MR jobs.

2) There should be a reason for a drastic difference in performance. This may be:

2.1 Different input format, other circumstances when benchmarking Pig vs Hive.

2.2 Combiner being disabled for some reason:
http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/perf.html#When+the+Combiner+is+Used
This happens to be the bottleneck for me in most cases.

And according to my experience there is no drastic difference in Pig/Hive performance.